# Force expansion of counter value in command argument

Tags: macros, counters, expansion, arguments

In the following MWE I would like to expand both `\envnum` as well as `\itemnum` while passing them to `\cmdwithexpandedargs`  but only the first one got expanded. Note the different output between `\wlog` and `\printcmd`, this still intrigues me.

```
\documentclass{letter}

\newcounter{nenv}
\newcommand\printcmd{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\cmdwithexpandedargs[1]{%
    \g@addto@macro\printcmd{#1 - }
}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{test}{%
    \stepcounter{nenv}%
    \let\olditem\item
    \renewcommand\item{%
        \olditem
        \xdef\envnum{\arabic{nenv}}%
        \xdef\itemnum{\alph{enumi}}%
        \wlog{\envnum.\itemnum}
        \expandafter\cmdwithexpandedargs\expandafter{\envnum\itemnum}%
    }%
    \begin{enumerate}%
}{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}
\begin{test}
  \item one
  \item two 
\end{test}
\begin{test}
  \item one
  \item two
  \item three
\end{test}
\printcmd
\end{document}
```

The `\wlog` output "1.a - 1.b - 2.a - 2.b - 2.c" is what I want, but it is not what `\printcmd` gives: "1c - 1c - 2c - 2c - 2c".
I'm accepting LaTeX3 (expl3) solutions here, if required!

Comment: Just use `\xappto\printcmd{#1 - }` from `etoolbox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand not only `\envnum`, but also `\itemnum`.  That means the one line got revised to `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\cmdwithexpandedargs\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\envnum\itemnum}`.  After the first round of expansion, `\itemnum` is expanded leaving what you started with, `\expandafter\cmdwithexpandedargs\expandafter{\envnum\itemnum}`.  This second round expands `\envnum` and you are good to go.

```
\documentclass{letter}

\newcounter{nenv}
\newcommand\printcmd{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\cmdwithexpandedargs[1]{%
    \g@addto@macro\printcmd{#1 - }
}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{test}{%
    \stepcounter{nenv}%
    \let\olditem\item
    \renewcommand\item{%
        \olditem
        \xdef\envnum{\arabic{nenv}}%
        \xdef\itemnum{\alph{enumi}}%
        \wlog{\envnum.\itemnum}
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\cmdwithexpandedargs\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\envnum\itemnum}%
    }%
    \begin{enumerate}%
}{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}
\begin{test}
  \item one
  \item two 
\end{test}
\begin{test}
  \item one
  \item two
  \item three
\end{test}
\printcmd
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**AFTERNOTE**

I got some magic code from Christian Tellechea:

```
% CODE FROM CHRISTIAN TELLECHEA
\makeatletter
\def\expandtimes(#1)#2#{\exp@ntimes@i(#1){#2}}
\def\exp@ntimes@i(#1)#2#3{%
    \ifnum#1>0 \expandafter\exec@first\else\expandafter\exec@second\fi
    {\expandafter\exp@second\expandafter{\expandafter\expandtimes\expandafter(\number%
      \numexpr#1-1)#2}}{#2}{#3}%
}
\long\def\exec@first#1#2{#1}
\long\def\exec@second#1#2{#2}
\long\def\swap@arg#1#2{#2{#1}}
\long\def\exp@second#1#2{\expandafter\swap@arg\expandafter{#2}{#1}}
\makeatother
%
```

that, if added to the preamble, would allow the multi-expansion syntax to be condensed to

```
\expandtimes(3)\cmdwithexpandedargs{\expandafter\envnum\itemnum}
```

to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is because you aren't expanding `\itemnum` when passing it to `\cmdwithexpandedargs`, but `\wlog` fully expands its argument.

You can do it more efficiently:

```
\documentclass{letter}

\newcounter{nenv}
\newcommand\printcmd{}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{test}{%
    \stepcounter{nenv}%
    \let\olditem\item
    \renewcommand\item{%
        \olditem
        \xdef\printcmd{\printcmd\arabic{nenv}\alph{enumi} - }%
        \wlog{\arabic{nenv}.\alph{enumi}}%
    }%
    \begin{enumerate}%
}{\end{enumerate}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{test}
  \item one
  \item two 
\end{test}
\begin{test}
  \item one
  \item two
  \item three
\end{test}
\printcmd
\end{document}
```

No need to do separate `\xdef` (global is actually useless and could simply be `\edef`).

[image]

In the log file you find

```
1.a
1.b
2.a
2.b
2.c
```

If you want to use `\cmdwithexpandedargs`, then you can do without `\expandafter` or fancy code.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\cmdwithexpandedargs[1]{%
    \g@addto@macro\printcmd{#1 - }
}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{test}{%
    \stepcounter{nenv}%
    \let\olditem\item
    \renewcommand\item{%
        \olditem
        \wlog{\arabic{nenv}.\alph{enumi}}
        \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
          \noexpand\cmdwithexpandedargs{\arabic{nenv}\alph{enumi}}%
        }\x
    }%
    \begin{enumerate}%
}{\end{enumerate}}
```

Comment: Your simplified solution works like a charm for this MWE but I need the other command (`\cmdwithexpandedargs`) in my full code. What I didn't understand is why `\arabic` and `\alph` didn't get expanded with `\xdef`. I thought there is no need to use `\expandafter` while using those `\xdef` (or `\edef`). But in this MWE everything works like those macros were never expanded, even with `\xdef`, why?

Comment: @bgeneto They did get expanded and their expansion assigned to `\envnum` and `\itemnum`. But you didn't expand both of these macros before passing the tokens to `\g@addto@macro`. I added a way with the intermediate step with `\cmdwithexpandedargs`.

Comment: You are right, in fact they got expanded in `\xdef`, but then not as argument to `\cmdwithexpandedargs`.  Thanks for such an elegant solution, as always!