# Adding current countervalue in macro to other variable?

Tags: macros, counters

I have trouble with expanding a counter inside another macro.
It seems that I cant use a simple chain of expandafter here since my counter can get very high. I found [Force expansion of counter value in command argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321428/force-expansion-of-counter-value-in-command-argument/321434) but could not figure out how to apply it in my examplecode:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcounter{Mynumbers}


\makeatletter
\def\printmylist{}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\addtomylist}[2]{ %
        \stepcounter{Mynumbers}%
        $^{( \theMynumbers , #1  ) }~$%
        }

\begin{document}

first\addtomylist{0}{one}\\
second\addtomylist{4}{four} \\

~
\printmylist \\

~\\~\\~\\~\\
expected outcome:\\
$first^{(1,0)}$ \\
$secound^{(2,4)}$  \\

1: one \\
2: four \\


\end{document}
```

Comment: I"m not sure what the problem is as it works foer me and I get your expected output (well, I really get `first$^{(1,0)}$ second$^{(2,4)}$`, but I think that this is what you intended). What error are you getting? Also, I am not sure if this is an accident or an artifact of your cutting it down to a MWE, but `\addtomylist` ignores `#2`.

Comment: @Andrew the missing part is the 1: one \\ 2: four \\

Comment: _never_ use `\\ ` at the end of a paragrah (it makes terrible output and tex warns about badness 10000 (which is the maximum badness possible)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what you are really trying to do there may be better ways of doing this. The following appears to produce your requested output, so I think that this may do what you want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\parindent=0pt

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\printmylist{}

\newcounter{Mynumbers}
\newcommand{\addtomylist}[2]{%
        \stepcounter{Mynumbers}%
        ${}^{(\theMynumbers, #1 )}~$%
        \xappto\printmylist{\theMynumbers: \unexpanded{#2\\}}%
        }

\begin{document}

first\addtomylist{0}{one}

second\addtomylist{4}{four}

\printmylist

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

I have used the `\xappto` command from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package. This command appends an expanded version of the second argument to the macro specified by the first argument:

```
\xappto<macro><stuff to append>
```

I have put `\unexpanded` because you don't want that part to expand when it is added to `\printmylist`.

Also, notice that I removed the space from the start of

```
\newcommand{\addtomylist}[2]{ % <-- unwanted space????
        \stepcounter{Mynumbers}%
        $^{( \theMynumbers , #1  ) }~$%
        }
```

This is what caused the gap between the `one` and the super-scripted `(1,0)` in your MWE.

Comment: Interestingly, you can use \par instead of \\ with no problems.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, you need `\noexpand\newline` or `\noexpand\\ ` but, as you say, `\par` is fine by itself (that is, you don't need`\noexpand`). The difference, I think, is that `\par` is not expandable whereas the others are.

Comment: @Andrew thank you very much for the fast solution! also a big thanks for the explanation, now I understand why my experiments failed badly ;)

Comment: The other difference between `\par` and `\\ ` is that `\par` is that putting `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph is always completely wrong and generates a spurious line of maximum badness 10000

Comment: @user2567875 The best way to thank, provided I've answered your question, is by adding a green tick.

Comment: @Andrew last time I accepted an answer right away I got scolded for not waiting 24h here ... "whatever I do: it's wrong :)"

Comment: I fixed the obvious error of leaving `#2` in the wild in an `\xdef`. Try your code with `\bfseries` in the second argument and you'll undersrand why.

Comment: @egreg I agree this is better, but for the advertised input this is not going to be a problem. Btw, do you always mean to be patronising or is it just that English is your second language?

Comment: @Andrew I fixed your wrong code and told you how you can check the issue. Is this patronizing?

Comment: @egreg Patrionise (verb): treat with an apparent kindness which betrays a feeling of superiority. As I said, perhaps it is just a question of language, especially as the internet is rife with misunderstandings. Anyway, you have convinced me to give TeX.SX a break for a while.

Comment: @Andrew If that's what you think, I apologize: it was never my intent to make you feel like that.

Answer (score 1):

The output you expect differs from the output you get in two aspects:

1. The phrases "first" and "second" are not in mathmode.
2. The macro `\printmylist` does not deliver the output `1: one \\ 2: four \\` .

Besides this you don't need `\makeatletter`and `\makeatother` with the definition of the `\printmylist`-macro as that definition does not contain the symbol "@".
Also the definition of your `\addtomylist`-command will contain space tokens that might produce horizontal space.

Here comes your code with slight modifications. I hope it now does what you wish it to do:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcounter{Mynumbers}

\newcommand*\printmylist{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addtomylist}[2]{%
  \stepcounter{Mynumbers}%
  $^{(\theMynumbers,#1) }~$%
  \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\printmylist\expandafter{\number\value{Mynumbers}: #2 \\}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$first$\addtomylist{0}{one}\\
$second$\addtomylist{4}{four}\\

\printmylist\\

\hrulefill\\
expected output:\\

$first^{(1,0)}$\\
$second^{(2,4)}$ \\

1: one \\
2: four \\


\end{document}
```

You might get better results using `\ensuremath`instead of `$..$`.

You might get better results either using `\par` instead of `\\` or wrapping things into `\hbox`es while via `\par` ensuring that TeX is in vertical mode where each outermost `\hbox` is treated a s a single line:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}

\newcounter{Mynumbers}

\newcommand*\printmylist{\par}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addtomylist}[2]{%
  \stepcounter{Mynumbers}%
  \ensuremath{^{(\theMynumbers,#1)}}%
  \expandafter\g@addto@macro
  \expandafter\printmylist
  \expandafter{%
  \expandafter\hbox
  \expandafter{%
  \number\value{Mynumbers}: #2}}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\verb|\parindent| is set to 1cm so you can see the difference between \TeX{}
acting in horizontal mode (where it also does the horizontal line-indenting with
the first line of a paragraph and the line breaking within a paragraph and the
\verb|\parfillskip|-glue-thingie at the end of a paragraph) and \TeX{} acting
in vertical mode where each outermost \verb|\hbox| is treated as a single
"line" whose content in turn gets processed in restricted horizontal mode:

\noindent\hrulefill

received output:

$first\addtomylist{0}{one}$

$second\addtomylist{4}{four}$

\printmylist

\noindent\hrulefill

expected output:

$first^{(1,0)}$

$second^{(2,4)}$

\hbox{1: one}
\hbox{2: four}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output after compiling the example]

Comment: Thank you for paying so much attention to the details!. I would have accept the other solutions as well if it were possible, but since it was the one I used in my document I did choose Andrews solution)

Answer (score 1):

You have to expand the counter's value before adding it to the list.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcounter{Mynumbers}

\newcommand\printmylist{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addtomylist}[2]{%
  \stepcounter{Mynumbers}%
  {\textsuperscript{(\theMynumbers,#1)}}%
  \edef\@tempa{\theMynumbers}%
  \expandafter\addto@mylist@\expandafter{\@tempa}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\addto@mylist@}[2]{%
  \g@addto@macro\printmylist{#1: #2\par}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

first\addtomylist{0}{one}

second\addtomylist{4}{four}


\printmylist

\end{document}
```

[image]

The mandatory `expl3` version:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtomylist}{mm}
 {
  \int_gincr:N \g_mylist_index_int
  \textsuperscript{(\int_use:N \g_mylist_index_int,#1)}
  \mylist_add:fn { \int_use:N \g_mylist_index_int }{ #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printmylist}{}
 {
  \seq_use:Nn \g_mylist_list_seq { \par }
 }

\int_new:N \g_mylist_index_int
\seq_new:N \g_mylist_list_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mylist_add:nn
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_mylist_list_seq { #1:~#2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mylist_add:nn { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

first\addtomylist{0}{one}

second\addtomylist{4}{four}

\printmylist

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.